# How python deals with module and package having the same name?

Tags: python, import, module, package

Suppose I have a module `foo.py` and a package `foo/`. If I call

```
import foo
```

which one will be loaded? How can I specify I want to load the module, or the package?

Comment: pythons import system is an unmitigated and ongoing travesty.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I believe the package will always get loaded. You can't work around this, as far as I know. So change either the package or the module name. Docs: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: Hi, can you please provide a reference for your claim?  I don't see anything in the documentation link provided that says the package will always be loaded in preference to the module.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The linked docs (for both Python 2 and 3) state that the directory of the current script is given preference in the search order. See also: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap

Comment: While docs says package is preferred over module in my experience it's not true, at least in python 2.7. It seems like in Python 2.7 import seeks for the module at parent (but not child) directories until it finds it, so **installed packages** will be checked at the end of resolving.

Answer (score 20):

Actually, it is possible, by manually guiding the import machinery to use a `.py` file instead of directory. (This code is not well tested, but seems to work). UPDATE 2020: Note that this requires using custom `import_module()` function instead of normal `import` statement. However, with modern Python3 and its `importlib`, it might be possible to make the bare `import` statement to work the same way too. (Note that this answer shows flexibility which Python offers. It's **not** an encouragement to use this in your applications. Use this only if you know what you're doing.)

File `foo.py`

```
print "foo module loaded"
```

File `foo/__init__.py`

```
print "foo package loaded"
```

File `test1.py`

```
import foo
```

File `test2.py`

```
import os, imp

def import_module(dir, name):
    """ load a module (not a package) with a given name 
        from the specified directory 
    """
    for description in imp.get_suffixes():
        (suffix, mode, type) = description
        if not suffix.startswith('.py'): continue
        abs_path = os.path.join(dir, name + suffix)
        if not os.path.exists(abs_path): continue
        fh = open(abs_path)
        return imp.load_module(name, fh, abs_path, (description))

import_module('.', 'foo')
```

Running

```
$ python test1.py 
foo package loaded

$ python test2.py 
foo module loaded
```

Comment: So, it's possible by manually hacking how imports are processed. That's great, and a worthy answer. But note that by manual hacking, almost anything is possible. So, I'm inclined to edit this answer, to emphasize "manual hacking" aspect.

Comment: Also note that hacking at the proper level (`importlib` import hooks), it might be possible to make the bare `import foo` to have a preference for `foo.py` the module instead of `foo/` the package.

Answer (score 15):

Maybe you want to move your classes from `foo.py` module to `__init__.py`.

This way you'll be able to import them from the package as well as importing optional subpackages:

File `foo/__init__.py`:

```py
class Bar(object):
...
```

File `foo/subfoo.py`:

```py
class SubBar(object):
...
```

File `mymodule.py`:

```py
from foo import Bar
from foo.subfoo import SubBar
```

Comment: I would like to know if it is ok to do this too.

Comment: Lennart Regebro recommended it in another answer so it is okay: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17530651/992687

Comment: simple, elegant and probably the only python-ish solution here