# How to structure python packages without repeating top level name for import

Tags: python, module, package

I'm brand new at python package management, and surely have done something wrong.  I was encouraged to create a directory structure as follows:

```
bagoftricks
├── bagoftricks
│   ├── bagoftricks
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── bagoftricks.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

bagoftricks.py contains two functions, `levenshtein()` and `geofind()`.

I would like to call these as:

```
import bagoftricks

x = bagoftricks.levenshtein(arg1,arg2)
```

Instead, I find I have to do this:

```
import bagoftricks

x = bagoftricks.bagoftricks.levenshtein(arg1,arg2)
```

Is there a better way to organize my packages in the first place, without the naming redundancy?

**UPDATE**

So, I followed Avichal Badaya's instructions below, and removed one level of nesting.  That is, I now have...

```
bagoftricks
├── bagoftricks
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── bagoftricks.py
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

However, to call this package, I still have...

```
from bagoftricks.bagoftricks import geofind()
```

or

```
import bagoftricks
```

then

```
>>> bagoftricks.bagoftricks.geofind()
```

Rather than the desired....

```
from bagoftricks import geofind()
```

or

```
import bagoftricks

>>> bagoftricks.geofind()
```

I cannot remove that extra layer of nesting.  When I try, by analogy, to remove one more level of nesting, so that my module is flat, as:

```
bagoftricks
├── __init__.py
├── bagoftricks.py
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

I cannot build the package at all...

```
$ python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
error: package directory 'bagoftricks' does not exist
```

What's the secret for natural imports like standard packages use, without redundant top-level name imports?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The first level "bagoftricks" is fine. That's just the name of your "project" so to speak. In the you have a setup.py, and other files that tell the packaging systems what they need to know.

You can then have the code directly in this module, or in a src directory. You can even go as far as just having this structure:

```
bagoftricks
├── bagoftricks.py
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

But I would not recommend that, mostly because you might want to reorganize things later, and it's easier if you already have a "proper" package. Also most people, tools and docs assume you have a package, so it's easier.

So the minimum would be:

```
bagoftricks
├── bagoftricks
│   └── __init__.py
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

With `__init__.py` containing the functions you want to import. You then use these functions like this:

```
from bagoftricks import levenshtein, anotherfunction
```

Once that `__init__.py` becomes too big, you want to split it up in several modules, giving you something like this:

```
bagoftricks
├── bagoftricks
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── anothermodule.py
│   └── levenshtein.py
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

Your `__init__.py` should then import the functions from the various modules:

```
from bagoftricks.levenshtein import levenshtein
from bagoftricks.anothermodule import anotherfunction
```

And then you can still use them like like you did before.

Comment: Thanks, that's clear and helpful, especially the tip about how to grow it effectively and properly.  The problem was definitely my __init__.py statement then.  I didn't quite understand where it sat in the hierarchy and where to put that to shorten the call.  Works perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: omg, I have been writing python for years and this is the first time I am ever hearing that the __init__.py file can contain something! I only ever had it floating around to indicate which directories were part of a module!

Answer (score 3):

with the updated structure you posted

```
bagoftricks
├── bagoftricks
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── bagoftricks.py
├── README.md
└── setup.py

into bagoftricks/__init__.py import all functions that you need

__init__.py
from bagoftricks import geofind, levenshtein
```

into a different program you can do the follwing

```
from bagoftricks import geofind
import bagoftricks; bagoftricks.geofind(); bagoftricks.bagoftriks.geofind()
```

note that you can import as well a wild card

```
from bagoftricks import *
```

Comment: Although importing wildcards like `from module import *` is considered very bad practice, because it can cause namespace conflicts. Always try to import by naming everything you import.

Comment: yes - you are right but for this example is fine - also note that modules from bagoftricks are imported into the namespace bagoftricks.

Comment: Just wondering; why is it fine for this example? If you import geofind from bagoftricks after which you import a function also called geofind from another module, you've got a conflict. What am I missing here? Why is this example different than other Python code? Importing with wildcards is bad practice, period.

Answer (score 1):

Follow following structure :

```
bagoftricks 
    ── bagoftricks
    │ ├── __init__.py
    │ └── bagoftricks.py 
    ├── README.md
    └── setup.py
```

and then you should be able to use it as :

```
from bagoftricks.bagoftricks import levenshtein, geofind
```

but after you make the change in folder structure do :-

```
pip uninstall <your package name mostly mentioned in setup.py>
```

and reinstall the package

meanwhile check your setup.py

```
#!/bin/env python
import os.path
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

def current_path(file_name):
    return os.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, os.path.pardir, file_name))

setup(
    name = 'bagoftricks',
    version = '0.1',
    include_package_data = True,
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

setup might have some other parameters too. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Is there any configuration that would let me do it with a single call?  Just `from bagoftricks import levenshtein, geofind` instead of the submodule call, `from bagoftricks.bagoftricks import levenshtein, geofind`?

Comment: @Mittenchops put `from . bagoftricks import levenshtein, geofind` in your `bagoftricks/__init__.py`