# Python Flask SQLAlchemy: Import app.db to /models/model.py is failing

Tags: python, flask, import, sqlalchemy, package

I feel I'm making a rookie error that I can't pin down.

I have the following folder structure

```
--MyAppRoot\
--app.py
----\models\__init__.py
----\models\models.py
----\models\data_handler.py
----\models\forms.py
----\models\a_few_other_py_files_etc.py
```

Where my app.py has the usual `Flask(__name__)` etc and `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` initialised. Everything works fine, all the imports from the various models py files work fine, usual stuff such as flask forms, wtforms etc.

Inside my data_handler.py file I am running a scraper which utilises Pandas to `.send_to_sql` however I now need to import db so I can execute a raw SQL `query` in `db.session.execute(query)` for a use in a Class but when doing so I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/me/PythonProjects/MyAppRoot/models/data_handler.py", line 7, in <module>
    from app import db
  File "C:\Users\me\PythonProjects\MyAppRoot\app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from models.forms import (RegisterForm,
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models.forms'; 'models' is not a package
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: the short answer: `\models\models.py` rename to `\some_other_name\models.py`

Comment: also suggest to read about Flask application factory pattern and blueprints before thinking about app dir structure (search in github for ` flask create_app`)

Comment: The stack trace show you are likely cyclic imports 
`models/xxx` require `app` also `app` require `models/xxx`,

I believe the `ModuleNotFoundError` came from incorrect `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Thank you @madzohan this was the correct answer. Worked perfectly and I've learnt not to name py files the same as directories. Please post as full answer and I will select thus so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem

While running `data_handler.py` python import system finds module named `models` on the same directory level (`models.py`). It doesn't look further through PYTHONPATH if name have matched.

> The directory containing the script being run is placed at the beginning of the search path
> https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

[How python deals with module and package having the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393861/how-python-deals-with-module-and-package-having-the-same-name)

### Solution #1

---

So you have to rename package or module name `\models\models.py` to make import system work properly.

#### Possible solution #2 (not sure)

---

You can try to run your script from `C:/Users/me/PythonProjects/MyAppRoot/` dir rather than from `C:/Users/me/PythonProjects/MyAppRoot/models/` in this way:

```
python -m models.data_handler
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I can confirm renaming `models/models.py` to `something_else/models.py` has fixed the issue.